# Sessions for GA pagepath and GA landing page path gives same output

Tags: analytics

I'm trying to get top 10 sessions for both page path and landing page path.
Unfortunately, I get the exact same result.
Is there an error in the API? Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: Examples of the paths etc is invaluable in recreating your issue.. You should always include a minimum working example in your questions and answers.

Comment: Hi all, 
I created 2 queries with a timing over the last 30 days: 
1: sessions, divided by dimension ga:LandingPagePath
2: sessions, divided by dimension ga:PagePath

Both give the exact same results. You would expect to have different outputs for each of them no?